# Disappeared blank space between span's after upgrade libraries

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, frontend

I upgraded my libraries from angular 11 to 15 and a lot of rest libraries (eg. boostrap and ngxboostrap to the highest versions).
After this operation I lost the empty space between some elements, e.g. span's.

Earlier version of the application:
[image: 1st]

Currently:
[image: 2nd]

My code from inspector:

```
<h4>
<span>Sammenlign</span>
<span>3/3</span>
</h4>
```

[image: summary]

Its looks like as if some pseudo element is defined or whatever else. When I tries to track this space in the inspector, I can't see anything. I looked at the `border box` also does not affect it, anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be a space between 2 `span` without a specific css rule.

You're observing the correct behaviour.

If you want your previous behaviour, a rule like following will do it :

```
h4 span:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 4px;
}
```